# How to use images in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to use an image in a label in Tkinter but always encounter "No such file or directory" error. I have also tried installing and importing the PIL library, but it still wouldn't work. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("My GUI app!")

image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('robot.png'))
label3 = Label(root, image=image1)
label3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is working. It 'robot.png' is  in current  working directory folder?